# windows CSP api

Tags: windows, cryptography, provider, cryptoapi

I am trying to write my own CSP. I am trying to do this by implementing a dll file, but I am not sure if I am on right way.

I found something like this:
Cryptographic Service Provider Developer's Toolkit (CSPDK)

there are samples with CSP API

CPAcquireContext
CPGenKey
... etc.

(it looks for me like an old api or api for winCE)

And here comes my question, which functions should I implement to provide new CSP for windows 7 and XP.

Is my plan good? - should I implement simple DLL and put her reference in register?
Or am i missing something?

Comment: What is the goal of writing new CSP?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to write a new CSP? Have you looked at the existing csp's? Yes, I am reiterating ognev.p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing [CNG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is a (long term) replacement for the MS Crypto API. You can create modules for that as well. Unfortunately it is only available since Vista. Windows XP is too old (and you should probably not be producing new applications for XP anyway).

Comment: yeah, but I have noticed that in win7 there are also registered CSP in register. I need them (CSP) to provide custom sign in some applications (IE, Word). Is there alternative for this kind of cases in CNG?

Comment: If the applications don't use CNG, then probably not, no.

Comment: @owlstead, We have many clients who still use XP and i donot see them dropping it in the near future. But they have now got the awareness/necessity to implement security features to their existing products, which means that we are in a stage of supporting both XP and the rest...Hence many people are forced to do development for the too old XP :)

Comment: In my opinion you cannot have a (complex) product such as XP, which is mostly out of support and security at the same time. Security requires maintenance. But I guess if the client insists...I would at least put in a disclaimer though.

Comment: There are Windows XP variants such as POS Ready 2009 which are still supported and will be until 2019 it looks like http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/product-lifecycles.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your HSM vendor will have their CSP written for you. You will get this csp when you install their driver. All you will be required is to access this CSP from your code.

To interface with your HSM vendor's CSP(check what they support), either you should use [PKCS#11](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2133) or use the [cryptoAPI CSP functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#csp_functions).

Comment: I am developing my own HSM. So I have to implement my CSP which is PKCS proxy - that is the goal :)

Comment: I don't know if this is a hobby project or not, but developing a commercial HSM is quite a lot of work, requires a lot of knowledge - and in the end you will have to CC or FIPS certify your product to have any chance in the marketplace. Think millions of dollars/euro's.

Comment: Maybe developing HSM is a big word :) We provide solutions based on JavaCard, so we need to integrate windows with our applet.